# What are the parameters for btHingeConstraint::setLimit?

Tags: physics, bullet-physics

What does each parameter in [`btHingeConstraint::setLimit`](http://bulletphysics.org/Bullet/BulletFull/classbtHingeConstraint.html#a99cfd186cc4f41246d1cac1ce840eb0d) do to the hinge constraint?

```
void btHingeConstraint::setLimit    (   btScalar    low,
        btScalar    high,
        btScalar    _softness = 0.9f,
        btScalar    _biasFactor = 0.3f,
        btScalar    _relaxationFactor = 1.0f 
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The parameters `low` and `high` are the angles restricting the hinge. The angle between the two bodies stays in that range. For no restriction, you pass a lower limit <= -pi and an upper limit >= pi here. This might be useful for things that rotate completely around other things, for example wheels on a car. For the other three parameters, I can only guess, so I don't claim this answer is complete.

`_softness` might be a negative measure of the friction that determines how much the hinge rotates for a given force. A high softness would make the hinge rotate easily like it's oiled then.

`_relaxationFactor` might be a measure of how much force is applied internally to bring the hinge in its central rotation. This is right in the middle of the low and high angles. For example, consider a western swing door. After walking through it will swing in both directions but at the end it stays right in the middle.

`_biasFactor` might be an offset for the relaxed rotation of the hinge. It won't be right in the middle of the low and high angles anymore. `1.0f` is the neural value.

I'll update this when I found out more. Currently, I can't test this manually, and the documentation seems to lack here.

Answer (score 0):

The `low` and `high` parameters are indeed the angle limits of the hinge, however the other three parameters (`_softness`, `_relaxationFactor`, and `_biasFactor`) can be set and are copied from the constraint to its `btAngularLimit` before it is "tested" but are never actually used.  It looks like plans to allow for soft constraint limits were never finished.